# spring cloud config server not loading file

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

I use spring cloud config server in spring boot.

There are two files in spring cloud config server repository.

1. common.yml
2. hazelcast-common.yml

common.yml

```
spring:
  hazelcast:
    config: classpath:hazelcast-common.yml
```

why not loading classpath:hazelcast-common.yml ?

I don't know the problem.

loading the classpath:hazelcast-common.yml

**this question resolved. github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/2344**

Comment: this question resolved. 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/2344